# Title of the instructor in charge

Tags: phrase-requests, epithet-requests

What do you call a university-level instructor/lecturer who’s in charge of a course? For example, suppose a course is split between two instructors, with one of them being responsible for the course as a whole. Are there any titles for this person which are more established than others? Some alternatives I’ve seen are main instructor, head instructor, or responsible instructor. Which is to be preferred, and are there any better alternatives?

(If the answer would vary by region, I’d prefer an American-style choice.)

Comment: You might need to consider something like *Course director*.

Comment: @AndrewLeach That is probably the best alternative as that seems to be used at places similar to mine. If you’ll post this as an answer I’ll gladly accept it.

Comment: If the down voter would like to comment with a reason, I’ll happily adjust my question accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

'Convenor' at my university in the United Kingdom. Not sure if this is just my institution, though.

Comment: This might be a good answer if you developed it a bit. As it stands, it is probably going to get deleted for being too short and for lacking support.

Answer (score 1):

Consider *course coordinator*. Have a look at the following. UCLA is a university in America; Monash is a university in Australia. (Emphasis, mine.)

> [**UCLA**](http://www.geog.ucla.edu/staff)
>
> Nick Burkhart - **Coordinator**, Geospatial @ UCLA
>
> Nick is responsible for coordinating participant affairs for Geospatial @ UCLA, the Department of Geography’s undergraduate and professional education program in geographic information science and technology.  His role includes support of program management, curricular initiatives and planning, developing online course content, online course management, and program outreach and evaluation.
>
> **[Monash University](http://med.monash.edu.au/policies/responsibilities-course-coordinator.html)**
>
> A **Course Coordinator** is responsible for ensuring effective management of a course and delivery of a coherent and relevant curriculum that aligns teaching, learning and assessment approaches within a strong pedagogical framework. The Course coordinator is also responsible for ensuring that delivery and management of the course follows Faculty and University education policies.

Comment: The UCLA example appears to be somewhat different, with the person in question coordinating a collection of courses for an educational program (and not being responsible for a single course). The Monash example, however, is right on point!

Comment: @hejseb Yes, I started with the Monash example but added UCLA because you were primarily interested in an "American-style choice". Note, though, that the UCLA *coordinator* position is also responsible for "course content" and "course management". His responsibility for multiple courses doesn't detract from him being *responsible* for each of them.

Comment: Yeah, that is true. Now that I knew what to search for I found that some departments in my country used both course coordinator and course director, with a subtle and unclear difference between them. Director, however, they translate into what I’d use in my native tongue, so I’ll go with that. But I couldn’t tell you (in any language) what the difference between director and coordinator is.